# Fluent Linq and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

This may be a silly question, but I have fluent linq query that is pulling data off a DB, but, of course, it processes the data in memory, not on the DB.

Is there a means of taking a query (Say table.Where(t => t. id > 22)) and having it run as a db query (i.e. SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID > 22).

I want to use the fluent style because I am building up the query from various places. I know I can make this specific query into query syntax, but my actual queries are more complex.

I have tried standard searches, but I suspect it is not going to be possible, as nothing comes up.

Yes using EF Core.

The code is not necessarily clear:

```cs
var getTableData = table.Where(base.whereSelection);
whereSelection.ForEach(w => getTableData = getTableData.Where(w));
```

At the moment, all of the Where Selections are Funcs - they could be converted to something else (like Expressions) if I knew that would make them run on the DB. The rest of the code is also building up this set of details programatically:

```cs
var selectedData = getTableData.Select(Convert);
var sortedTableData = GetSort(selectedData, Ordering);
var sorted = PickDataFrom(sortedTableData);
return CheckAndTake(sorted, pageSize);
```

Everything seems to work. Just in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you using EF Core? Can you provide code samples?

Comment: Query syntax is just syntax sugar. It is still Method chain (Fluent) after compilation. And what is the question? Use what you prefer.

Comment: `table.Where(t => t. id > 22)` will be executed on the DB when `table` is a `DbSet` or a `Queryable` created by EF. Most likely you made a mistake when you are building your query. Could you show us that code, please?

Comment: Edited to respond to comments.

Comment: Not *like Expressions* but ONLY Expressions. Then LINQ provider will translate your `Where` to the SQL. But looks like you are on wrong track from the start.

Comment: OK, then I can do that and see. Thank you.

I get that I might be. But for the moment, we have what we have and need to work and progress with it.

Comment: I do not see what you have. Names of the methods. Show implementations. If they are `IQueryable` and written correctly - it may work.